# Can you play Summoner Wars with only the Second Summoner packs?

Tags: summoner-wars

If I want to play with the second summoner of a particular faction, do I have to use cards from both the original summoner pack and the second summoner pack, or can I use only the cards from the second summoner pack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cards from just the Second Summoner deck without mixing them in with the original faction decks. In fact, this is how my wife and I play; we keep each deck in its original form rather than deckbuilding. If you look at the descriptions for the packs on [Plaid Hat Games website](https://www.plaidhatgames.com/games/summoner-wars) (emphasis mine):

> **This Second Summoner deck is a full faction deck with its own Summoner, set-up card, Champions, Commons, Walls and Event Cards.** *It requires a Summoner Wars Master Set or Starter Set to play.*

The part in bold is what you care about; it's a fully functional deck on its own. The part in italics might be your concern. The reason you need a starter or master set is to get the player boards/mats and the tokens. However, you can [buy the board](https://www.plaidhatgames.com/store/734) on its own, and you can use anything from pennies to Skittles for wound tokens, so even a base set is sort of optional.